# Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Getting Error Like 
An attempt was made to call the method org.elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.create(Lorg/elasticsearch/action/admin/indices/create/CreateIndexRequest;[Lorg/apache/http/Header;)
Lorg/elasticsearch/action/admin/indices/create/CreateIndexResponse; but it does not exist. Its class, org.elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/audit.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-6.7.0.jar!/org/elasticsearch/client/IndicesClient.class
```

It was loaded from the following location:

jar:file:/audit.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-6.7.0.jar!

Please Help me out to solve this issue

Comment: What versions of Spring Boot and Spring Data Elasticsearch are you using?

Comment: This error normally comes up when using a different Elasticsearch client version than the one that Spring Data Elasticsearch was built with. So my question would be the same as Andy's: what version of Spring Boot (and Spring Data Elasticsearch) do you use?

Comment: Springboot 2.1.0 But i have externally included elasticsearch in gradle file
org.elasticsearch 6.8.5

Answer (score 3):

Spring Boot 2.1.x uses Spring Data Elasticsearch 3.1.x which in turn is built against the libraries of Elasticsearch 6.2.2.

If you want to use Elasticsearch 6.8.5 you need to upgrade your Spring Data Elasticsearch version to 3.2.3 which is built against Elasticsearch 6.8.4.

I don't know if Spring Boot 2.1.0 can handle this in it's autoconfiguration, you might have to annotate your application with:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration.class)
```

and configure Spring Data Elasticsearch by yourself.